# Error : Failed to allocate memory: 1455 when try to run my app in eclipse emulator in 2560x1600 xhdpi

Tags: android-emulator

When i create an emulator with specifications 
[image]

**when I try to run my project on it , I get error
[2014-01-04 20:27:47 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 1455
[2014-01-04 20:27:47 - Emulator] 
[2014-01-04 20:27:47 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2014-01-04 20:27:47 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.**

*my laptop has following specifications*
[image]

Please help what configuration should I use to make it run !

Answer (score 0):

Change RAM configuration to 128 or 64.